# Transferring lightroom catalogue to a new computer

Tags: lightroom

I  have a new computer running windows 8. I have installed on it a legal, paid for Lightroom CC on it. Can I transfer the catalogue in my 'copied' Lightroom 4 which is running on my old windows 7 computer without any problems. If so, what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Copy the catalog folder to the new computer and open it.  If you have any images located outside the folder, you will also have to copy them over and may have to do some missing file discovery to re-wire things up, but it should be pretty easy.  I routinely move my Lightroom catalogs between different drives and computers.

Answer (score 3):

You can export your catalogue, copy it to your new machine, then open it up there. This way you won't lose any pictures no matter where they're saved.